# Implementing PJAX - Configuring Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, server, pjax

My first question here.

I searched thoroughly, and unfortunately, I am unable to find an explanation I can understand.

I am interested in understanding how PJAX works (link below), so that I can consider implementing it.  It seems simple enough, but the requirement to configure the server to recognize PJAX requests has me stumped. I am a front-end developer that is completely unfamiliar with back-end development.

For example, how do I configure the server? The PJAX author gives an example in RAILS, so it is a matter of placing that code wherever it goes?

I build custom and implement Wordpress, and I use a Wordpress hosting solution. Does that affect where I would configure the server?

I know these are general questions, which demonstrate how little I know.  I would appreciate if someone could explain the concept of configuring the server and perhaps provide an example of what that would look like.

I appreciate your help.

https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax